# Python : Making a negative image of a RGB picture

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I've been fiddling around with Python for hours now, trying to figure out how to turn my colored image into a color negative and I just can't seem to be able to figure it out..

I've imported PIL and Image from PIL andI know that I need to do something similar to (255.0 - red, 255.0 - green, 255.0 - blue) in order to negate the image, but I just can't seem to be able to figure out how to incorporate that into my 'for' loop.

I'm really not that good at python at all, and any help would really be appreciated =/

thankyou in advance :)

Comment: Or better yet, show us all the relevant code that you have written.

Answer (score 7):

```
inverted = Image.eval(original, lambda(x):255-x)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not, myself, a PIL user, but a quick search of [the documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imageops.htm) turned up an `invert` function.

```
ImageOps.invert(image) => image
    Invert (negate) the image.
```

Perhaps that's what you're looking for?

Comment: i was wondering if there was a way to do it without using the invert function.. like with the actual values themselves?

Comment: You probably need to look into `im.tostring` and `im.fromstring`. This will also require you to get acquainted with Python's `struct` module.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this thread is pretty old but, I came across this in my travels and thought it was relevant, hope it's of some help.

```
def invert():
    picture=makePicture("C:/somepic.png")
    for px in getPixels(picture): 
       r=getRed(px) 
       g=getGreen(px) 
       b=getBlue(px)
       newColour=makeColor(255-r,255-g,255-b) 
       setColor(px,newColour)
    repaint(picture)
```

Comment: Does this require a particular package to be imported? `makePicture` doesn't seem to be part of standard python.

Comment: ahhh of course, that's my bad. Rookie error. I'm learning jython in JES which must have some funky extra little bits and pieces included.

Answer (score 1):

```
for r,row in enumerate(myPicture):
    for c,value in enumerate(row):
        myPicture[r][c] = invert(value)
```